# When drawing a rectangle why is a coordinate with the formaula x = y +y*3 + y different from x = y*4?

Tags: java, recursion

For an assignment I was tasked on creating a recursive method in order to create a Sierpinski Carpet. For my code one of my calculations was not given the correct output so I had to switch my formula for another that should give the same result but didn't. Here is the code that actually works.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HW2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button enter = new Button("Display");
        Label number = new Label("Enter in Order:");
        TextField input = new TextField();
        HBox v = new HBox();
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Pane p = new Pane();
        h.getChildren().addAll(number, input, enter);
        h.setSpacing(10);
        pane.setBottom(h);
        // pane.setCenter(v);
        pane.setCenter(p);
        h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        v.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 900, 900);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Square Fractal");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        enter.setOnAction(e -> {
            points(Integer.parseInt(input.getText()), p);
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void points(int x, Pane p) {
        p.getChildren().clear();
            draw(200, 350, 350, p, x);
    }

    public static void draw(double size, double a, double b, Pane p) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(a,b,size,size);
        p.getChildren().add(r);
    }

    public static void draw(double size, double a, double b, Pane p, double amt) {
        if (amt == 0) {
            draw(size, a, b, p);
        } else {
            draw(size, a, b, p);
            double size2 = size / 3;
            double a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3;
            a1 = a - 3 * size2 + size2;
            a2 = a + 3 * size2 + size2;
            a3 = a + size2;
            b1 = b + 3 * size2 + size2;
            b2 = b - 3 * size2 +  size2;
            b3 = b + size2;


            draw(size2, a1, b1, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a1, b2, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a2, b1, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a2, b2, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a1, b3, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a2, b3, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a3, b1, p, amt - 1);
            draw(size2, a3, b2, p, amt - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

for the chunk of code `

```
 double size2 = size / 3;
    double a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3;
    a1 = a - 3 * size2 + size2;
    a2 = a + 3 * size2 + size2;
    a3 = a + size2;
    b1 = b + 3 * size2 + size2;
    b2 = b - 3 * size2 +  size2;
    b3 = b + size2;
```

if I replace it with

```
double size2 = size / 3;
double a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3;
a1 = a - 4 * size2;
a2 = a + 4 * size2;
a3 = a + size2;
b1 = b + 4 * size2;
b2 = b - 4 * size2;
b3 = b + size2;
```

the rectangle positions are all out of place.

What is the difference between 4*size2 vs 3*size2 + size2, and why does the former not work?

Comment: Order of operations. The first one is interpreted as `(a - (3 * size2)) + size2`.

Comment: Because Y + 3Y + Y is Three Ys and 2 more Ys (five Ys)

Comment: `x = y +y*3 + y` is `x = 5*y`

Comment: `a1 = a - 2*size2` and `b2 = b - 2*size2` would be correct.

Comment: @infixed read the question before answering maybe

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ^

Comment: @Bálint well I did read the title

Comment: Yeah, that's not enough

Comment: @Bálint The fault is the OP's. He should reconcile his title and his question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at these 2 rows:

```
a1 = a - 3 * size2 + size2; // original
a1 = a - 4 * size2;  // replaced
```

So, what happens in the first one? You take `a` subtract `3 * size2` from it, then you add size2.

The second one takes `a` and subtracts `4 * size2` from it.

The first row pretty much subtracts only 2 times size2 from a, while the second one subtracts 4 times size2.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, (x = y + 3y + y) != (x = 4y). The first equation in your question is simply (x = 5y) and that will only equal (x = 4y) when y=0.

Really, the problem here is order of operations. The working code is interpreted as ((a - (3 * size2)) + size2). Your revision is interpreted as (a - (4 * size2)) and these two will never be equal.

Comment: "*The first equation in your question is simply (x = 5y) and that will never equal (x = 4y).*" It will for `y=0`.